# codeigniter image upload watermark and thumbnail

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am uploading an image using CI upload library work fine, problem with watermarking and image thumbnail, if id do watermarking first and then thumbnail, its doing watermarking to original image but also re-sized it thumbnail size but not keeping original size image with watermark too, if i do thumbnail first then watermark it work fine but i want thumbnail also watermarked here is my code

```
$this->do_thumb('file_name');
$this->watermark('file_name');

function watermark($filename){
        $image_cfg = array();
        $image_cfg['image_library'] = 'GD2';
        $image_cfg['source_image'] = 'upload/' . $filename;
        $image_cfg['wm_overlay_path'] = 'upload/watermark.png';
        $image_cfg['new_image'] = 'upload/mark_'.$filename;
        $image_cfg['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
        $image_cfg['wm_opacity'] = '10';
        $image_cfg['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
        $image_cfg['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
        $image_cfg['create_thumb'] = FALSE;

        $this->image_lib->initialize($image_cfg);
        $this->image_lib->watermark();
        $this->image_lib->clear();

//        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
//        die();

    }

    function do_thumb($filename) {
        $image_cfg['image_library'] = 'GD2';
        $image_cfg['source_image'] = 'upload/' . $filename;
        $image_cfg['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $image_cfg['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $image_cfg['width'] = '200';
        $image_cfg['height'] = '175';
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($image_cfg);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $this->image_lib->clear();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you watermark the thumbnail too? Just make your watermark image suitable for you thumbnail.

Comment: that is the problem i watermark image first then thumbnail it save only one thumnail with watermark not the original image with watermark and thumbnail with watermark

Comment: Do you get any errors from ` $this->image_lib->display_errors();`?

Comment: its not giving any error at all. thing are working fine its doing resizing and watermarking but keeping only one image either watermarked thumbnail or without watermark thumbnail.

Comment: Set `'new_image'` in `do_thumb()` and try to pass it in `watermark()`.

Comment: well do_thumb is doing the same thing no need to put new_image it create another image as thumbnail with adding thumb in name you can see create_thumb config is true it will create your_image_name_thumb.jpg as new image well i put the same problem on CI forums months ago too but no reply

Answer (score 2):

Execute `watermark()` first, then `do_thumb()`, remove `$image_cfg['new_image']` at watermark function or if you want to use it, pass `$image_cfg['new_image']` value to `do_thumb()`.

Also dont forget to set `$image_cfg['new_image']` at `do_thumb()` so it create new thumb file not rewrite it

The problem why your thumb not contain watermark is because you use original image not the watermarking image as the image source for the thumb. hope you understand what i mean cos english is not my first language, php it is ..

Comment: well thanks for the solution i already did the same thing for one of my project where i was creating on fly watermark and thumb of images first i was creating watermark with new_image then creating thumb from this new_image name and work really perfect i will also share my code